# vsts: Index & Publish symbols with core 2.0 not working

Tags: build, .net-core, azure-devops

I'm having issues getting Index & Publish symbols task in vsts work with core 2.0.
Is it not supported yet?
The build task is called: Index Sources & Publish Symbols (Preview).

I Know that it's working for asp.net as i have tested that and i'm able to debug into the lib i created. But for dotnet core 2.0 i'm not able to debug into the lib. it does not find the source, and it's not trying to login to vsts to get the source as it does with asp.net.

Comment: Can you show the detail steps for how did you debug the project? And does the lib project referring the .dll you built in VSTS and is the .pdb file also added in the new created lib project?

Comment: i created a dotnet core web project, and used nuget to get the package i wanted to debug into. i set a breakpoint on the entrypoint to the class thats in the package. and run. and this is the screen i get:Message.cs not found Locating source for 'd:\a\1\s\helloworld2\Message.cs'. (No checksum.)
...
Looking for source using source server...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: d:\a\1\s\helloworld2\Message.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'd:\a\1\s\helloworld2\Message.cs'.

Comment: using the publish symbol path in vsts seems fine: 
Succeeded processing D:\a\1\s\publish\helloworld2.dll: helloworld2.dll/995715CF8000/helloworld2.dll/Binary
Succeeded processing D:\a\1\s\publish\helloworld2.pdb: helloworld2.pdb/48B07C637F544E01930060C413EB3577FFFFFFFF/helloworld2.pdb/Private
Published 4 files.
{"name":"navis/hello world core libsdebug/hello world core libsdebug.2018.1.10.1/4335/4a15dfb4-bcb0-443d-9f6c-77625b5c65ab","status":3,"storageETag":"W/\"datetime'2018-01-10T09%3A59%3A52.6412355Z'\"","url":"https://hrmts.artifacts.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Since your VSTS account is private, can you add related screen shot? And for the .net core web project you debug, how did you connected the `.pdb` file with the project?